# How might I make this code continue till a correct answer is picked?

Tags: java, cmd

I'd like this block of code to continue till a acceptable answer(ie. 1,2,3,4) is entered, but I don't know how I would do this. Thank you. Also if there is any other way that would simplify this that would also be helpful.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class NewMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input;
        Scanner keyboard =  new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Your choice\n[1]Up \n[2]Down \n[3]Left \n[4]Right");
        input = keyboard.nextLine();

        if(input.equals("1")) {
            System.out.println("You are going up!!!");
        }
        else {
            if(input.equals("2")){
                System.out.println("You are going down!!!");
            }
            else {
                if(input.equals("3")) {
                    System.out.println("You are going left!!!");
                }
                else {
                    if(input.equals("4")) {
                        System.out.println("You are going right!!!");
                    }
                    else{}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Short answer, loops.  E.G.  [for](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) & [while](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html)..  Try something with those, then get back to us when you have a more specific question.  Voting to close this one.

Comment: I would definitely recommend checking out the [`switch` statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html), instead of those nested `if`/`else`s.

Comment: can you give an example how i would be able to use a switch statement?

Comment: Like this e.g. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

Comment: @user3059855 - [user2320094's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20576590/1454048) is your example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try with switch case http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

your case:

```
while(flag == false){

    switch (imput) {
        case "1":         
        System.out.println("You are going up!!!"); flag=true;
        break;

        case "2":  
        System.out.println("You are going down!!!"); flag = true;
        break;

        case "3":  
        System.out.println("You are going left!!!"); flag = true;
        break;

        case "4":   System.out.println("You are going right!!!"); flag = true;
        break;
    }

}
```

and you can put the optional condition `default:`

Comment: but if the user put in a unacceptable answer it won't repeat it self till there is one

Comment: yes, you're right, i edit whit while loop, sorry.

Comment: Thank you, if I had more rep i'd up vote it.

Comment: This switch statement will only work if you are using JDK 7, since that's when they added support for strings inside switch statements.

Answer (score 2):

You could wrap it in a while statement...

```
while(!input.equals("1")
        && !input.equals("2")
        && !input.equals("3")
        && !input.equals("4"))
{
    input = keyboard.nextLine();
}
```

This says continue to get the input while the value is not 1, 2, 3, or 4. You should probably also initialize input to some random value before the while statement (a value different from 1, 2, 3, or 4)

Comment: Hey, do you mind if I edit your answer to put the while-loop onto multiple lines? (it'll be the exact same code, but it'll be all visible without having to scroll)

Comment: Looks like someone more or less already beat you to the punch

Answer (score 2):

You can put a `while` loop around your input, until the user enters "quit". Like this:

```
...
System.out.println("Your choice\n[1]Up \n[2]Down \n[3]Left \n[4]Right");
while (true) {
    input = keyboard.nextLine();
    if (input.equals("1")) {
        System.out.println("You are going up!!!");
    }
    else if(input.equals("2")) {
        System.out.println("You are going down!!!");
    }
    else if(input.equals("3")) {
        System.out.println("You are going left!!!");
    }
    else if(input.equals("4")) {
        System.out.println("You are going right!!!");
    }
        else if (input.equals("quit")) {
        break;
    }
        else {
            System.out.println("Incorrect input!");
        }
}
```

Comment: Maybe `switch`/`case`s instead of `if`/`else`?

Comment: You can't use strings in a switch statement unless you are using JDK 7.

Comment: Ok. I was just going off of [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html).